# Can I set a limit to the set of duplicates in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

IP_table:

| ip_src | sys_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0.0.0 | 1 |
| 0.0.0.0 | 2 |
| 1.1.1.1 | 3 |

Sys_table:

| sys_id | owner |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |

When I do INNER JOIN on these tables I get result as

IP_table:

| ip_src | sys_id | owner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0.0.0 | 1 | A |
| 0.0.0.0 | 2 | A |
| 1.1.1.1 | 3 | C |

Now my query is that is there a way where I can set a limit to the ip_src where I should be getting set of ip_src.
For ex: If I set limit as 1, I should get 2 rows (0.0.0.0 and  0.0.0.0) since they are duplicates. And if I set limit as 2 I should be getting (0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0 and 1.1.1.1)
I want the limit to work on the group of duplicates and not on rows.

Comment: Compute `dense_rank() .. rnk` and  limit it in the outer query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in mysql you can :

```
select * from IP_table i
join Sys_table s on i.sys_id = s.sys_id
and ip_src in (select distinct ip_src from IP_table order by ip_src limit 2)
```

and you can change limit each time

or you can use window function :

```
select * from (
select * , dense_rank() over (partition by ip_src order byip_src ) rn 
from IP_table i
join Sys_table s on i.sys_id = s.sys_id
) t 
where rn <= 2
```

and change rn value